# Leibniz's Derivative Rule for Integral in Measure Theory

Tags: calculus, integration, measure-theory, derivatives

I saw the extension of Leibniz rule for integrals for measure theory on [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Measure_theory_statement), although I am not sure if the proposition there is correct. Besides there is no proof for it. Can anybody please introduce a reference for the measure theoretic version of it?

The statement on wiki is as follows:

Let $X$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ , and $\Omega$ be
a measure space. Suppose $f: X \times \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ satisfies the following conditions:

::(1) $f(x,\omega)$ is a Lebesgue-integrable function of $\omega$ for each $x \in X$

::(2) For almost all $\omega \in \Omega$ , the derivative $f_x$ exists for all $x \in X$

::(3) There is an integrable function $ \theta: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $|f_x(x,\omega)| \leq \theta ( \omega)$ for all $x \in X$

Then for all $x \in X$
::$ \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} x} \int_{\Omega} \, f(x, \omega) \mathrm{d} \omega = \int_{\Omega}  \, f_x ( x, \omega) \mathrm{d} \omega $

Comment: Because it is not free to access, I will go ahead and emphasise that the [only reference](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2319163) of the Wikipedia article does not include the measure theoretic statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check [this link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160508220010/http://people.hss.caltech.edu/%7Ekcb/Notes/LeibnizRule.pdf) out, specially the proposition in section 2

Comment: perhaps this should be a comment

Comment: @Hassan A if you write the answer fully yourself, I will accept it.